# Data import process was successful but 0 data imported

Tags: mysql, import, workbench

Am new to SQL and am trying to import CSV file into existing tables and the process is always successful but the end result is that 0 records imported. when I tried to import in a new table i got the below error. hope you can help

```
Starting...
Prepare Import...
Prepare Import done
Import data file....
- Drop existing table

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 266, in prepare_new_table
    self._editor.executeManagementCommand(""" CREATE TABLE %s (%s)""" % (self._table_w_prefix, ", ".join(["`%s` %s" % (col['name'], col["type"]) for col in self._mapping if col['active'] is True])), 1)
grt.DBError: ("Table 'item' already exists", 1050)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 197, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 131, in start_import
    retval = self.module.start(self.stop)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 300, in start
    ret = self.start_import()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 412, in start_import
    if not self.prepare_new_table():
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 277, in prepare_new_table
    self._editor.executeManagementCommand(""" DROP TABLE %s""" % self._table_w_prefix, 1)
grt.DBError: ("Cannot drop table 'item' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'fk_orders_item1' on table 'orders'.", 3730)
ERROR: Import data file: ("Cannot drop table 'item' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'fk_orders_item1' on table 'orders'.", 3730)
Failed
```

The tables were generated from EER diagram.

Comment: `"Table 'item' already exists"` Does this give you a clue

Comment: It looks like your script is first trying to drop a table before recreating it.  However, the `DROP TABLE` command is failing because there is a foreign key constraint.  Then the `CREATE TABLE` command is failing because the table already exists (because it wasn't dropped).  So first you'll need to remove the foreign key constraint (see 'orders' table).